# Set Component State Synchronously on ComponentWIllReveiveProps

Tags: reactjs

I am passing props from Dashboard component to Modal Component when I click an item in the Dahboard table row. When the row is clicked, the data in that row is passed as props to the modal and the modal set its state on ComponenentWIllReceiveProps synchronously so it renders in the Modal Input box and textarea
How do I set the state in modal with props passed down from Dashboard.js and render them in the modal inpputbox and textarea

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Modal from '../Modal/Modal'
import add from '../../images/add.png'
import addSelected from '../../images/addSelected.png'
import './Dashboard.css'

const TableRow = ({ row, openQuoteDetails, deleteQuote }) => (
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" onClick={openQuoteDetails}>{row.author}</th>
    <td onClick={openQuoteDetails}>{row.quote}<small id="admin" className="form-text text-muted">{row.admin}</small></td>
    <td><i className="fa fa-close" onClick={deleteQuote}></i></td>
  </tr>
)

const Table = ({ data, openQuoteDetails, deleteQuote }) => (
  <table className="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr className="table-active">
        <th scope="col">Author</th>
        <th scope="col">Quote</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map((row, index) =>
        <TableRow key={index} row={row} openQuoteDetails={() => openQuoteDetails(row, index)} deleteQuote={() => deleteQuote(row, index)} />
      )}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      quotes: [
        {
          "quote": "Our industry does not respect tradition - it only respects innovation.",
          "author": "Satya Nadella",
          "admin": "Joseph Akayesi"
        },
        {
          "quote": "Engineering is the closest thing to magic that exists in the world.",
          "author": "Elon Musk",
          "admin": "Joseph Akayesi"
        },
        {
          "quote": "For me, it matters that we drive technology as an equalizing force, as an enabler for everyone around the world.",
          "author": "Sundar Pichai",
          "admin": "Yasmin Adams"
        }
      ],
      addSource: add,
      isModalOpen: false,
      index: '',
      author: '',
      quote: ''
    }
  }

  onAddMouseOver = () => {
    this.setState({ addSource: addSelected })
  }

  onAddMouseOut = () => {
    this.setState({ addSource: add })
  }

  toggleModalOpenOrClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen })
    this.setState({ index: '' })
    this.setState({ author: '' })
    this.setState({ quote: '' })
  }

  openQuoteDetails = (row, index) => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
    this.setState({ index: index, author: row.author, quote: row.quote })
  }

  deleteQuote = (row, index) => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
    console.log('Row deleted')
    console.log(this.state.quotes.splice(index, 1))
  }






  render() {
    return (
      <div className='pt-3'>
        <Table
          data={this.state.quotes}
          openQuoteDetails={this.openQuoteDetails}
          deleteQuote={this.deleteQuote} />
        <div className='text-center align-items-center justify-content-centerpt-5'>
          <a href='#add' onClick={this.toggleModalOpenOrClose}>
            <img src={this.state.addSource} className='addButton mx-1' alt="add" onMouseOver={this.onAddMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.onAddMouseOut} />
          </a>
        </div>
        <Modal
          isModalOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
          toggleModalOpenOrClose={this.toggleModalOpenOrClose}
          data={this.state}
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          addNewQuote={this.addNewQuote}
          updateExistingQuote={this.updateExistingQuote} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard
```

**Modal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Modal.css'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addQuote } from '../../actions/quoteActions'

class Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: '',
            author: '',
            quote: '',
            errors: {}
        }
    }

    onInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value })
    }

    switchSaveChangesAction = () => {
        return this.props.state.index ? this.addNewQuote : this.updateExistingQuote
    }

    addNewQuote = () => {
        const { user } = this.props.auth

        const newQuote = {
            admin: user.id,
            quote: this.state.quote,
            author: this.state.author,
        }
        console.log('Add New')
        console.log(newQuote)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log('receive props')

        if(nextProps.author !== this.props.author){
        this.setState({ author: nextProps.author})
        }
        // this.setState({ id: this.props.data.index })
        console.log(nextProps)
        this.setState({ author: this.props.data.author }, () => console.log(this.state.author))
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    updateExistingQuote = (index) => {
        console.log('Update Existing')
        console.log(this.props.state.author)
        console.log(this.props.state.quote)
        console.log(this.props.state.index)
    }

    render() {
        let showOrHideModal = this.props.isModalOpen ? 'modal d-block' : 'modal d-none'

        // let selectedQuoteDetails = {
        //     id: this.props.data.index ? this.props.data.index : '',
        //     author: this.props.data.author ? this.props.data.author : '',
        //     quote: this.props.data.quote ? this.props.data.quote : ''
        // };

        // let modalInputValue = selectedQuoteDetails ? selectedQuoteDetails : this.state
        let saveChangesAction = this.props.data.index >= 0 ? this.updateExistingQuote : this.addNewQuote
        return (
            <div className={showOrHideModal}>
                <div className='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                    <div className='modal-content'>
                        <div className='modal-header bg-light'>
                            <h5 className='modal-title'><b>Add a Quote</b></h5>
                            <button type='button' className='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close' onClick={this.props.toggleModalOpenOrClose}>
                                <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='modal-body'>
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label htmlFor='author'>Author</label>
                                <input type='text' className='form-control' id='author' aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='Enter author' onChange={this.onInputChange} defaultValue={this.state.author} />
                            </div>
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <label htmlFor='quote'>Quote</label>
                                <textarea className='form-control' id='quote' rows='3' placeholder='Enter quote' onChange={this.onInputChange} value={this.state.quote}></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='modal-footer'>
                            <button type='button' className='btn btn-primary' onClick={saveChangesAction}>Save changes</button>
                            <button type='button' className='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal' onClick={this.props.toggleModalOpenOrClose}>Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Modal.propTypes = {
    addQuote: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addQuote })(Modal)
```

Comment: You need to ask a question

Comment: @SrThompson How do I set the state in modal with props passed down from Dashboard.js and render them in the modal inpputbox and textarea ?

Comment: Add the question to "the question". The way you're using it, it doesn't make much sense to have state inside Modal, you can just keep the state in the parent component and pass it as props to the modal. `componentWillReceiveProps` is getting deprecated and that's not a good way to use it, since you're not deriving state from props, just copying a prop to the state. That can cause nasty bugs and infinite rendering loops. I suggest you either remove the state from Modal or else use props only to initialize it, and then handle internally until it's ready

Comment: @SrThompson I use props to initialize state but it doesn't render immediately. I am trying to make it render immediately so it shows in the input boxes once the modal is open

Comment: According to your example, you're not. `componentWIllReceiveProps` doesn't fire on mount. State should be initalized in the constructor.